# How to download pdf from url and view the downloaded pdf in the android app itself?

Tags: android, pdf, download, android-webview

I am creating a magazine android app in which i need to download the PDF from a URL then open the downloaded document in the app itself using web view.

I have tried loading directly URL into web view using google docs but that does not work as the the PDF itself is quite big.

Answer (score 4):

Simply use this :

```
    String URL="http://yourdomain.in/yourpdf_file.pdf";

FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
     fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            globalProgressDialog.ProgressDialogShow(MainActivity.this);

            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(URL));
            startActivity(browserIntent);

            globalProgressDialog.dismissProgressDialog();


        }
    });
```

Comment: This just opens a up a browser man!

Answer (score 0):

Loading a pdf file using google docs isn't good idea. Because there is

> the bandwidth limit for viewing or downloading files that aren't in Google Docs format

I advice you to use [this](https://github.com/voghDev/PdfViewPager) library.